# Show geoJSON properties in jQuery Mobile Panel

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-mobile, leaflet, geojson

First off I'm a novice at JS so please bear with me if this is a simple task to complete.

I'm currently using the stock [LeafletJS popup bubble](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html)  to display the properties from my geoJSON. However, I would like to utilize the jQuery Mobile Panel to display the properties from my geoJSON file when it is clicked on, it is similar to the OpenLayers example [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile-jq.html).  Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Here is the js that I am using to load the geoJSON as well as the stock popup from Leaflet:

```
$.getJSON(dict[geoJSON Variable Goes here],
  function(data){
    L.geoJson(data, {
      style: style,
       onEachFeature: function (feature, layer){
         if (feature.properties.SOMETHING == 0){
             return layer.bindPopup("<b><em>" + feature.properties.Name + "</em> LABEL<br />LABEL</b>");}
            else if (feature.properties.Attacks == 1){
                     return layer.bindPopup("<b><em>" + feature.properties.Name + "</em> LABEL<br />" + feature.properties.SOMETHING + " label</b>");}
            else {
                  return layer.bindPopup("<b><em>" + feature.properties.Name + "</em> LABEL<br />" + feature.properties.SOMETHING + " label</b>");
                            }
                        },
                    }).addTo(GROUPLAYER FOR LAYER ON/OFF);
                });
```

I am using jQuery Mobile to display multiple maps and right now everything is working fine but the geoJSON has a lot of data that I need to show so any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: can u show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible.

Simply use:

```
marker.on("click",popMobilePanel);

function popMobilePanel(event){
   //make your modal appear  
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that only work for a simple marker? not a geoJSON where you need to 'onEachFeature' ?

Comment: Yes sorry. I looked at your open layer example with markers and I forgot you were using geojson. I'll update my answer.